# My boxplots merge all in one plot when i run the code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to plot several boxplots. For that I have a pandas series containing float64 values. (example: last values of timeoverall1)

```
    timeoverall1
1352     89.611111
1353     95.964167
1354     71.482222
1355     94.788611
1356     71.475278
1357     70.289167
Length: 1057, dtype: float64
```

I transform the series into arrays (i dont know if its even needed but my source suggested it so i better did).

```
bpoverall
  94.78861111,
  71.47527778,  
  70.28916667])
```

Now here is what I did exactly for you to reproduce:

```
#put into arrays to make plotready
bpoverall = np.array(timeoverall1)
bpstockout = np.array(timestockout1)
bpindig = np.array(timeindig1)
bppacking = np.array(timepacking1)
bpend = np.array(timeend1)

#print boxplots
boxplot1 = plt.boxplot(bpoverall)
boxplot2 = plt.boxplot(bpindig)
boxplot3 = plt.boxplot(bpstockout)
boxplot4 = plt.boxplot(bppacking)
boxplot5 = plt.boxplot(bpend)
```

So when I run the code step by step i get 5 several boxplots, as i like. But when i run all of the code at once i get this:

[image: All boxplots are merged in one]

Where does this mistake occur? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html), you should pass all data in one call:

```
boxplot = plt.boxplot([bpoverall, bpindig, bpstockout, bppacking, bpend])
```

Or you could put each plot in its own `Axis`, using subplots:

```
nrows = 2
ncols = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)
datasets = [bpoverall, bpindig, bpstockout, bppacking, bpend]
for data, ax in zip(datasets, axes.ravel()):
    ax.boxplot(data)
```

Comment: the values are very different. example: bpoverall are all values combined but the others are just fractions of these values. I would prefer to get several boxplots to fit the scaling

Comment: If they have different scale you need to either normalize your data, or plot them in different axes of figures. I'll edit my answer to include this.